# How to call node-schedule scheduler dynamically in nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-schedule

I am writing an api for quiz game in which i have to schedule job dynamically for giving question to player.

For that I have used `node-scheduler` and on game start I am setting schedule of 30 sec. Now I have new challenge if a player give answer within 30 seconds like on 10 or 20 seconds then he will get new question and scheduler will set on next 30 seconds from it. Again if player will answer in 30 seconds then a new question will be fired inconstantly and next scheduler will be set.

I have am using node-scheduler to schedule jobs. And these will be dynamically added on player join.

Can any one help me or can share some snippet of code that do similar type of job?

Comment: Can't you just use the `cancel()` method for a job to end it early if the user clicks submit on that particular question?

Comment: Is there any way to call that schedule earlier and the after that it sets to 30 seconds ?

Comment: How are you setting your scheduler?  Are you literally just scheduling a new question every 30 seconds using `node-scheduler`?

Comment: No I am setting scheduler for 30 minutes that will execute a method in every 30 seconds to fire question.  `schedular.scheduleJob({ start: startTime, end: endTime,rule: '0-59/30 * * * * *' }, async (data) => {
    let questReq = {
        'teamId' : roomId
    };
    const question = await findQuestion(questReq);
    
    /** Event to fire question to Player on joinned socket Room */
    global.io.sockets.in(roomId).emit('fireQuest',question);
});`     Can suggest better way to do this.

Comment: Ok I understand a bit better.  How about instead of a scheduler you just use `setTimeout`?  You can have a call to load the next question within the timeout and set the time for 30 seconds.  If the user clicks on something earlier, you can get the ID of the timeout and call `clearTimeout()` to stop the timer for that question and move on.